# XSLT Oxygen - Automate transformations

Tags: xslt, oxygenxml

I use Oxygen to perform some XSLT transformations but I would like to automate the transformations I have to do. Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are any number of technologies you can use: shell scripts, Ant, XProc, hand-written Java or C# or PHP or Javascript, Orbeon, Coccoon, you name it. Pretty well anything except oXygen! What are your constraints?